# "Wither" meaning in this context: "Wings sprouted from each wither - vast, black leathery wings"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> Wings sprouted from each **wither** - vast, black leathery wings that looked as though they ought to belong to giant bats.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

I think **wither** is used as a noun word. But I can't find it's a noun in dictionaries. The only one I get is "withers" means "*the highest part of a horse’s back, above its shoulders*". Does this use of *wither* mean the same as *withers*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The author used the singular form of **[withers](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/withers)**:

> **Withers**: (veterinary medicine) The part of the back of a four-legged animal that is between the shoulder blades; in many species the highest point of the body and the standard place to measure the animal's height.
>
> [image]

The meaning is "wings sprouted from the withers of each horse", or "wings sprouted from each horse's back".

Formally, *withers* can only be used in the plural, but I guess that the author has used her [writer's license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license) to "invent" singular **wither**.

Comment: But dictionaries don't suggest it can be used as a singular, do they?

Comment: @dan  - yes, exactly. The author has used her writer's license to "invent" singular **wither** to use it as a synecdoche for **horse**.

Comment: I don't think it's a synecdoche for horse. It could be simply a singular form of "withers" there.

Comment: I agree with @dan. There is only one beast involved here, with two withers.

Comment: Ah! I see. I did not read the text closely enough. I thought it refered to multiple horses.

Comment: In context, I think the author assumed "wither" was roughly synonymous with "shoulder"; the intended image is that this animal has two wings, one sprouting from each side of its back, at the withers.

Comment: There are 2 problems with plurals in that sentence, because bats only have two wings... I would have written “Two vast, black leathery wings that looked as though they ought to belong to a giant bat sprouted from its withers.” The author knows how to spin a good tale, but she really isn’t very good language-wise.

Comment: @ColleenV Although it’s not actually specified in the books (as far as I can recall), thestrals are usually depicted as having two wings in total, which would indeed make the sentence numerically inaccurate: “a wing sprouted from each wither” would have been more precise, though it lacks some of the dramatic effect of the original. But even the plural doesn’t _necessitate_ that there be several wings per wither; somehow, _each_ makes it possible (for me at least) to read ‘cumulatively’, with one wing per wither, resulting in a totality of wings sproutying.

Comment: Note that _withers_ has also been used in the singular, though less commonly so; Rowling didn’t invent it. The OED has five citations of the singular, spanning from 1607 to 1908 (article last updated in 1928).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet My point is really that Rowling is crap at using language to paint a picture of something. How many wings and how many withers? No-one knows after reading that sentence save Rowling.

Comment: @ColleenV I actually come to the opposite conclusion: it doesn’t really matter how many wings there are per wither, but the structure of the sentence uses language very efficiently at painting a picture.

Comment: @ColleenV: Oh no. Any other universe we'd know there were only two wings but this one doesn't even physics.

Comment: @ColleenV - She knows the word "wither" as a noun applied to horses, and manages to use it almost entirely correctly. I expect that's better than most people can manage.

Comment: OK, I have read and enjoyed Harry Potter too, so I’m not saying she’s a bad writer. Not every book must be elevated beyond a good story. I just don’t think her use of language is that great. Novels aren’t supposed to have “efficient” language. They aren’t textbooks. We aren’t supposed to applaud writers for using words mostly more correctly than your average person. Regardless it’s my opinion  that she abuses words like “withers” to try to sound more literary than she is, when she’d be better sticking with vocabulary she is comfortable with.